# SQL Query loop through two arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I am using the below SQL Query in a PHP application to find matching id for each stop.

```
$sql = "SELECT trip_id FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id='5897' AND stop_id='1373'";
```

What I would like to do is to have it loop through my two arrays `$toStop` and `$fromStop` and find `trip_id`'s that matches then output the results.

```
$toStop = array("1373","1376","1372","7316","5697","2748","2749","1375","1377","7368","1374","2787","2788");
$fromStop = array("5897","7311","7146","7129","0020","3705","0039","7128","3806","7152","7190","5941","5185","7189","0001","0038","0021","3394","0019","0031","7155","0030");
```

Something like this? But I don't think this would work.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); ++$i) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($array2); ++$i) {
            SELECT trip_id FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id=$array1[$i] AND stop_id=$array2[$i]
    }
}
```

Sample of Database after query:

```
SELECT trip_id, stop_id
FROM `stop_times`
WHERE stop_id = '1538'

L66220600132482     1538
0051ML66220630143389    1538
0051ML66220700154239    1538
0051ML66220715159618    1538
0051ML66220730165473    1538
0051ML66220745170994    1538
0051ML66220800176259    1538
0051ML66220815181524    1538
0051ML66220830185989    1538
0070ML577519153855214   1538
0070ML577520154046960   1538
0070ML577521154237374   1538
0072ML577707101039907   1538
0072ML577707351095644   1538
0072ML577708101171393   1538
0072ML577708451246468   1538
0072ML577715402171497   1538
0072ML577716102237827   1538
0072ML577716402305231   1538
0072ML577717102370287   1538
0072ML577717402429337   1538
0074ML575808001813962   1538
0074ML575808051829094   1538
0074ML575808051833737   1538
0074ML575808351938317   1538
0074ML575808351942909   1538
0074ML575809052042897   1538
0074ML575809052043418   1538
0074ML575809152083611   1538
0074ML575809352147477   1538
```

|

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, but perhaps you just want something like `"... WHERE stop_id IN (".implode(',', $stopArray1).") ..."`?

Comment: I just updated with an example for clarity. It would loop though each value in one array with every value in another array for for a match.

Comment: what do you mean with "find trip_id's that matches" if is the same column stop_id only match when is the same id, then you have something like this SELECT trip_id FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id=5897 AND stop_id=1

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer The SQL works fine if I have just single stop_id value to compare. However, I have two arrays each with at least 10 different stop_id's. I want to find a way of comparing the trip_id's associated with each stop_id and find if they have the same trip_id ie.. Are in the same route line.

Comment: Well you'd need to use `stop_id='5897' OR stop_id='1373'` in your query to get all rows with either of the two values. If you use `AND` it will search for a row that has stop_id 5897 but also stop_id 1373, which isn't possible.

Comment: @CodedMonkey Sorry, I mustn't be explaining this very well. That is an example of two stop_id's. they could potentially be 20 of each that I need to compare against. hence the arrays.